# The status of the MQFTE agent is in problemm state. What is the reason for it and how can this be rectified?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, agent, websphere-mq-fte

The status of the MQFTE agent is in problem state. What is the reason for it and how can this be rectified ?

Comment: For troubleshooting: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/troubleshooting_general.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" status is seen when the agent is publishing status information but the publications are out of date when received by the tool.

Such a condition indicates the command handler thread is no longer
processing the agent command queue. This means either there is an
internal problem or more likely the agent has been flooded with transfer
requests that have a large source wildcard/recursive component. If this
is case then additional command handlers can be allocated using agent
properties [`maxCommandHandlerThreads`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/properties.htm&resultof=%22maxCommandHandlerThreads%22%20%22maxcommandhandlerthread%22).